# Segmentation fault(core dumped) c++

Tags: c++

The following program gives the correct output but gives segmentation fault(core dumped in the end)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[50],n,i,c[50],b[50];
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    cin>>a[i];
    for(i=1;i<=100;i++)
        b[i]=0;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        b[a[i]]++;
    }
    for(i=2;i<=100;i++)
    {
        b[i]=b[i]+b[i-1];
    }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        c[b[a[i]]]=a[i];
        b[a[i]]--;
    }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cout<<c[i]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the debugger output
[gdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hokBM.png)

Comment: `b` is an array of size 50 (which means you can index from 0 to 49) but you loop from 1 to 100, of course it doesnt work....

Comment: Don't access arrays outside their range, in this case 0 to 49

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from other conditions in your program, at least this loop causes a buffer overflow and hence invokes *undefined behavior*!

```
for(i=1;i<=100;i++)
        b[i]=0;
```

That is, because `b` has only 50 elements, and you're accessing memory waaay beyond that range. Also C arrays a zero-index based.

Note, that you likely cause UB in other statements as well, but this one was the first I noticed skimming over your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are going out of bounds here:

```
for(i=2;i<=100;i++)
{
    b[i]=b[i]+b[i-1];
}
```

since `b` is an array of size 50 and you allow `i` to reach the value of 100 and index the array. This causes the segmentation fault.

PS: Other loops may also index your arrays out of bounds, depending on the input you receive, since you don't check the input.